# Blender 2.8x Outliner - Manually Reorder Objects within Collection

Tags: outliner

In my Blender project I have collections like so:

[image: Screenshot of Blender Outliner]

And I would like to manually reorder the objects within the collections. For example, within the collection named **Fat Donuts**, I would like the order to be:

```
Letter D...
Letter O...
Letter N...
Letter U...
Letter T...
Letter S....
```

I cannot get those items to change order using straight drag-and-drop. I did notice that the order is initially based upon the order in the items are placed into the collection.

I have turned off sorting as you can see here:

[image: Screenshot of outliner filter options]

I know it is possible to manually reorder elements within collections, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've mentioned, uncheck '**Sort Alphabetically**' first to allow manual arrangement. After doing that you should be able to reorder the layers by clicking and dragging them around.
The dark highlight over a collection indicates that you're joining your current selection to another and the dark line indicates that you're placing a collection above/below another collection. 
Holding down control while dragging a collection parents the current selection to the one you're dragging it into but still allows it to be higher up the hierachy.

Maybe this question was asked before a newer Blender release and a potential issue was resolved. (Using Blender 2.81a)

Comment: Yes, this was indeed fixed in a newer release, so I am going to mark it as resolved.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work in version 2.91.0. I've disabled "Sort Alphabetically" but objects are still don't reorder when I drag them.

Comment: Same here. Not working for 2.92 Beta

Comment: In case someone wonders, manual re-ordering of the objects in Outliner currently is still not allowed - https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/68502